# Flask, uwsgi, nginx can't access os level commands

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I've written a site in `flask`, which works perfectly from the debug server, but when deployed on a combination of `uwsgi` and `nginx` it fails to be able to run any commands from the command line. For example one of the parts of the script attempts to access the `os.environ['HOME']` it can't find it. One of the scripts attempts to run a command line program but it again complains of not being able to find it. I'm running `nginx` as my user and I can definitely see and use all of these things.

I'm guessing that `uwsgi` or `nginx` runs in a 'space' that is unable to see the os or something? How can I change this or get around it?

The errors are the following (these are started from a new python thread from the flask site so maybe that is important)

Traceback for the environment variable:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./app/views.py", line 236, in chooseRecon
    from nipypeNiftiConvert import niftiReconstruction
  File "./app/nipypeNiftiConvert.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nipype import logging, configNipype
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils.config import NipypeConfig
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/utils/config.py", line 21, in <module>
    homedir = os.environ['HOME']
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'HOME'
```

The second error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/pipeline/plugins/multiproc.py", line 18, in run_node
    result['result'] = node.run(updatehash=updatehash)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/pipeline/engine.py", line 1386, in run
    self._run_interface()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/pipeline/engine.py", line 1496, in _run_interface
    self._result = self._run_command(execute)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/pipeline/engine.py", line 1622, in _run_command
    result = self._interface.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/interfaces/base.py", line 946, in run
    runtime = self._run_interface(runtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/interfaces/dcm2nii.py", line 50, in _run_interface
    new_runtime = super(Dcm2nii, self)._run_interface(runtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nipype/interfaces/base.py", line 1376, in _run_interface
    (self.cmd.split()[0], runtime.hostname))
IOError: dcm2nii could not be found on host nu.pst.ed.ac.uk
Interface Dcm2nii failed to run.
```

Comment: What is the error? `HOME` does not exist or it can't be accessed somehow? Post your code.

Comment: The errors are the following (these are started from a new python thread from the flask site so maybe that is important) `IOError: *program* could not be found on host` and for the environ `homedir = os.environ['HOME']
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'HOME'
`

Comment: Always post *full* tracebacks. They are long for a purpose

Comment: Posted back to back here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b084719eeb494cb8d7d1